# iOS XML parsing on main or background thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, ios, sax, xml-parsing

When parsing XML in Objective-C on an iOS app, when can the main thread be used and when should the parsing happen on a background thread? Can the main thread handle SAX parsing on small documents, or should *all* XML parsing happen in the background?

Comment: Parsing works quite nicely in the background.  Just be sure that when you want to update the UI you always do it on the main thread.  GCD makes this painless with inline blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I normally do all of my data processing on a background thread. This ensures that the UI thread isn't blocked at any point in time by whatever I'm doing.

Answer (score 4):

Anything that does not call into UIKit (UIView & it's subclasses) or even suggests that it might render to the screen is completely safe to do off the main thread.

I've got several apps that process XML on a background thread. I would suggest using a NSOperation that you pass the entire XML document to, allow it to process it completely or provide a series of delegate methods that notify the main thread about it's progress. If you plan on using core data, might i suggest [my own NSOperation abstract class](https://github.com/veritech/FRCoreDataOperation) for doing background imports.

In fact you can do some rendering on a background thread, but you must pick your API's very carefully.